# Are DOM elements treated as objects?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

Hello I am new to javascript and I came across this code which I don't quite get
and the code is

```
let element = document.querySelector(".some-class")
element.x = "hello world"
console.log(element.x)
```

And this code logs `hello world` to the console.
So my question is that are the DOM elements treated as objects(because in objects we use the same syntax like `obj.color` for example.)
And what does that `x` mean in general?

Comment: (almost) everything in javascript is an Object - `what does that x mean in general` ... what does it mean to you? you created it :p (well, you didn't, but you get my meaning)

Comment: Welcome to javascript, where almost everything is an object (including functions). You can give them additional fields whenever you like, like in your example where you added `x`.

Comment: [Some documentation about `Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which is what is returned by [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: "Is it an object?" in JS is answered by "Is it not a primitive?". DOM elements are not primitives.

Comment: If you `console.log(element)`, you will see all attributes which are returned from `querySelector`, and it's literally an object. `element.x` is actually you're extending the existing object on `element`

Answer (score -2):

With `element.x` you added a attribute to your `element` object, with just this code, `document.querySelector(".some-class")` is useless, it would do the same if you just had declared an empty variable `element`.

However, you can edit the element in the HTML with this syntax, for example

```
let element = document.querySelector(".some-class");
element.innerHTML = "bb";
```

Comment: If it was an attribute, then why don't I see it when I console.log the element? the output would look something like this - `<div class="some-class";></div>hello world`  and I am not interested in innerHTML right now, the code is actually used to set css style like this - `element.style.top = element.x + "px"`

Comment: @ShreejaGeeda If you `console.log(element)`, you will see a attribute `x` at the end of your element. The attribute x does not exist by default but with `element.x = "hello world"` you created it. If you want to add something in the HTML, you have to use an existing one like `element.innerHTML`, `element.textContent` or `element.outterHTML` (more complete list [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp))